# When changing location.hash in onclick it changes to undefined

Tags: javascript, html, undefined

I have such code:

```
$(e).click(function() {
    console.log(this.href);
    location.hash = this.href;
});
```

Here `e` is a `<li>` element like this: `<li href="#about">About</li>`
`location.hash` has onchange listener:

```
$(window).hashchange(function() {
    if (location.hash=="") location.hash="me";
    $(".content").spin();
    $(".content").load("http://example.com/inc/"+location.hash.substr(1), function() {
        $(this).spin(false);
    });
});
```

**UPD: Problem is not with variable accessing, because console.log prints right value of variable.**

Comment: href is not a valid attribute of LI

Comment: Just FYI, adding a `href` attribute to an `<li>` element is not valid. If you want to store some value on the li-element, you should consider using the `data-*` attributes instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

href is not a valid attribute of LI

Add data-href (or perhaps better:data-hash) to your LI

```
<li data-href="somevalue">...
```

and use

```
$(e).click(function() {
    location.hash = $(this).data("href");
});
```

Comment: Forgot about this. Thanks, dude! :)