# Java generic prevent type mismatch error due access to generic static field

Tags: java, generics

I have these three classes:

```
public class EntityType<T extends Entity> implements Serializable {

    public String mRelationType;
    public Class<T> mClass;
    public int mTypeId;
    public int mTypeTitleId;

    public EntityType(final int typeId, final Class<T> entityClass, final String relationType, final int typeTitleId) {
        this.mTypeId = typeId;
        this.mClass = entityClass;
        this.mRelationType = relationType;
        this.mTypeTitleId = typeTitleId;
    }
    ...
}

public class MyApplication extends Application {
    ...
    public static HashMap<Integer, EntityType<? extends Entity<?>>> entityTypes;
    ...
}

public abstract class Entity<T extends Entity<T>> {

    public static <T extends Entity<T>> List<T> getAll(final EntityType<T> type) {
        return getDao(type.mClass).queryForAll();
    }

    public static <T extends Entity<T>> List<T> getAllOrphans(final EntityType<T> type) {
        try {
            return getDao(type.mClass).queryBuilder().where().isNull(Column.PARENT).query();
        }catch(SQLException e){
            return new ArrayList<>();
        }
    }

    public static <T extends Entity> T getById(final EntityType<T> type, final int id) {
        return getDao(type.mClass).queryForId(id);
    }


    //TODO: Fix warnings
    public void save() {
        getDao(getEntityType().mClass).createOrUpdate((T) this);
    }


    public void remove() {
        getDao(getEntityType().mClass).delete((T) this);
    }

    public static <T extends Entity> RuntimeExceptionDao<T, Integer> getDao(Class<T> entityClass) {
        return MyApplication.getDBHelper().getRuntimeExceptionDao(entityClass);
    }

    public T getSingle(List<T> entities) {
        return !entities.isEmpty() ? entities.get(0) : null;
    }

    public List<T> getRelated(final EntityType<T> type){
        return MyQuery.getAllRelated(getEntityType(), getId(), type);
    }

    public boolean hasNote(){
        return !getRelated(MyApplication.entityTypes.get(NoteEntity.TYPE)).isEmpty();
    }
    public abstract EntityTypeClass<T> getEntityTypeClass();
    ...
}
```

The problem I have is that I can't access the hashMap in method hasNote() because of error:

```
Error:(89, 61) error: incompatible types: EntityType<CAP#1> cannot be converted to EntityType<T>
where T is a type-variable:
T extends Entity<T> declared in class Entity
where CAP#1 is a fresh type-variable:
CAP#1 extends Entity<?> from capture of ? extends Entity<?>
```

However, if i will change signature of hashmap to HashMap, it will compile, but give me a warning "unchecked assignment". But i want to neglect as much warnings, as possible.

Comment: Provide mode code, it's not obvious from the shortened snippet.

Comment: I get it compiled. In Eclipse and with javac. Your question's code obviously does not reflect what you really have.

Comment: That's the thing, it is compilable.

Comment: How here's some more code

Comment: Please indent it properly, it's hard to tell which method belongs to which class.

Comment: Yep, i've indented it

Comment: Would you consider revisiting and possible accept old answers such as mine from 2013? http://stackoverflow.com/a/14355743/295783